# Displaying elevation profile and storing DEM elevation back to KML line using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, elevation, profile

When I draw a track in Google Earth, for example along a road, I can right-click it to "Show elevation profile", and it displays a 2D plot of distance vs elevation. However, if I save the KML, the elevation coordinate is always zero.

So let's suppose I import the KML LineString in QGIS, and I have a SRTM DEM layer, how can I:

1. Display an elevation profile (distance along road vs DEM elevation at point);
2. "Replace" the (zeroed) elevation profiles of KML by DEM elevation values, so that I could export back to kml and have elevation "hardcoded" in the LineString.

Comment: If case of I have many polylines in polyline vector (with diffirently ID). How can I make the profile automatic and then save table as excel (csv) file associated with diff ID? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download and use a plugin called "Profile tool".

- load your grid
- load your polyline (layer)
- run plugin (Plugins/Profile tool/ Terrain profile)
- in field called "Selection" (below the profile chart) choose "Selected polyline" and choose your line

[image: Profile tool - Terrain profile]

To simply get all grid values along the line switch tab from "Profile" to "Table" and there you can copy all values to clipboard and paste to text editor / table editor...

[image: Profile tool - Terrain profile as values]

Comment: I'm gonna take a look and post some feedback as soon as I get some spare time. Thanks for the answer! (I use Dufour, so I expect some thrill...)